# Get last record from Core data base

Tags: swift, core-data

How would i get in correct way last record from the data base ? For now I am getting last record but i can not cast it. The warning says "Cast from '[Class]' to unrelated type 'Class' always fails". Is it other way to get properties from this result ?

```
   let _context = DataBaseController.getContext()
                    let _fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Class> = Class.fetchRequest()
                    do {
                        let _allElements = try _context.count(for: _fetchRequest)
                        _fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
                        if _allElements == 1 {
                            _fetchRequest.fetchOffset = _allElements
                        } else {
                            _fetchRequest.fetchOffset = _allElements - 1
                        }
                        _fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                        do {
                            let _result = try DataBaseController.getContext().fetch(_fetchRequest) as! Ping

                        } catch {
                            print("Error \(error)")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error \(error)")
                    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that even if you fetch only one, it will return an array of one, si maybe `let results = try DataBaseController.getContext().fetch(_fetchRequest) as [Ping]; let _result = results[0] as Ping`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Core Data fetch returns always an array of managed objects

```
let _result = try DataBaseController.getContext().fetch(_fetchRequest) as! [Ping]
if !_result.isEmpty {
   let lastItem to _result[0]
}
```

Comment: By meaning of _result[0] it's going to return last record from the data base ? It's LIFO ?

Comment: Using a `fetchLimit` of 1 there can be only **one** item in the array.